# How are stronger $H^n \subseteq P$ or $H \subseteq \sqrt{P}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, lie-algebras, ideals

Let $L$ be a Lie algebra over k and $H, P$ are ideals of Lie algebra $L$

Set $H^1:=H$. Define recursively $H^{n+1}:=[H,H^n]$ for all $n≥1$. Then $H^{n+1}=[H,H^n]⊆H^n$ for all $n$.

$\sqrt{P}= \cap \{M \subseteq L$ : M is prime ideal containg $P \} $

How are stronger $H^n \subseteq P$ or $H \subseteq \sqrt{P}$ ?

In other words which one implies the other

$H^n \subseteq P \textit{ for some } n \in N $ $\implies$ $H \subseteq \sqrt{P} $

or

$H \subseteq \sqrt{P}$ $\implies$ $H^n \subseteq P \textit{ for some } n \in N $

or

they are not comparable.

Any help would be appreciated.

> New Update: In the case of rings.

Let $R$ be a ring, and suppose that $H, P$ are two ideals of the ring $R$

$$\textbf{Definition i)} \quad \sqrt{P} = \{r \in R: r^{n} \in P \textit{ for some } n \in N\}$$

$$\textbf{Definition ii)} \quad H^{n}=\left\{h^{n}: h \in H\right\} \subseteq P \textit{ for some } n \in N$$

$$1) \quad H^n \subseteq P \textit{ for some } n \in N$$
$$2) \quad H \subseteq \sqrt{P}$$

Proof:-

$1) \to 2$) Suppose that $H^n \subseteq P$, let $h \in H$,  then $h^n \in H^n$,  hence $h^n \in P$, because $H^n \subseteq P$, thus $h \in \sqrt{P}$. Therefore $H \subseteq \sqrt{P}$

$2) \to 1$) Suppose that $H \subseteq \sqrt{P}$, let $h^n \in H^n$,  then $h \in H$,  hence $h \in \sqrt{P}$, because $H \subseteq \sqrt{P}$, thus $h^n \in P$. Therefore $H^n \subseteq P $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a complete answer but I hope the ideas are helpful.

The first implication is true, that is $H^n \subseteq P \implies H \subseteq \sqrt P$. Hint: If $M$ is prime ideal containing $P$, show that $H^n \subseteq M \implies H \subseteq M$.

I suspect the converse is not true however I do not have any immediate counterexamples.

Your proof for $(2) \implies (1)$ in the ring case is not correct. Remember that $h \in \sqrt{P}$ does not imply that $h^n \in P$ for all $n$. Unless you have some added assumptions about your ring, you cannot immediately conclude that there is a uniform constant $n$ such that $h^n \in P$ for all $h \in \sqrt{P}$. Below is an interesting example of this.

**Example (Zassenhaus).** Let $F$ be a field and $I = (0,1)$ be the open interval in $\mathbb{R}$. Define a vector space $R$ over $F$ with basis $\{x_i : i \in I\}$. Define multiplication on this basis by
$$
x_i x_j = \left\{
\begin{array}{!}
x_{i+j} & \textrm{if } i+j < 1, \\
0 & \textrm{otherwise.}
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Extend this multiplication linearly to $R$. Let $P$ be the ideal generated by $\{x_i : i > 1/2 \}$. If you play a little with this ring you'll see that $\sqrt P = R$. However for all $n > 0$, we have $(x_{1/(2n+1)})^n \not\in P$

Comment: Firstly, $P$ may be not prime ideal !! Why you repleace $P$ by $M$.
How are you state that  : If $M$ is prime ideal containing $P$, show that $H^n⊆M⟹H⊆M$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment, I have not assumed $P$ is a prime ideal. The hint is to show the implication directly from the definition of prime ideal. For completeness, the definition of pirme ideal that I use is: $M$ is prime if $[A, B] \subseteq M \implies A \subseteq M$ or $B \subseteq M$

Comment: please, could you give me more clarification ?

Comment: In order to show that $H \subseteq \sqrt P$ we need to show that for every prime ideal $M$ containing $P$, that we have $H \subseteq M$. If this holds then we have that $H \subseteq \cap \{M : M $  a prime ideal containing $ P \}$.

Comment: See my update, I was added $\textit{ for some } n \in N$

Answer (score -1):

$$H \subseteq \sqrt{K}  \implies H^n \subseteq K \textit{ for some    } n \in N $$

**Proof by contrapositive:-** (P $\implies$ Q) $\equiv $ ( ¬Q $\implies$ ¬P)

Let $H$ and $K$ be two ideals of Lie algebra $L$ such that $H^n \not  \subseteq K $

Now, suppose that $x \in K-H^n$ for some $n \in N$

$\implies$ $x \in K \subseteq \sqrt{K}  $, and $ x \not \in H^n$ for any $n \in N$ thus $x \not \in H^1=H.$

$\implies$ $x \in \sqrt{K}-H $

$\implies$ $H \not \subseteq \sqrt{K}$

Therefore $H \subseteq \sqrt{K}  \implies H^n \subseteq K \textit{ for some } n \in N $

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg. Is this true?

Comment: No. Small issue: Negation of "$H^n\subseteq K$ for some $n$" is "$H^n \not \subseteq K$ for *all* $n$". Big issue: Your next-to-last line is wrong: existence of $x \in \sqrt K - H$ does not imply $H \not \subseteq \sqrt K$, but rather that $\sqrt K \not \subseteq H$ (which already follows immediately from the assumption).

Comment: Do you have an idea to prove this?

Comment: No, I do not. --

Answer (score -1):

$$H \subseteq \sqrt{K}  \implies H^n \subseteq K \textit{ for some    } n \in N $$

**Proof by contrapositive:-** (P $\implies$ Q) $\equiv $ ( ¬Q $\implies$ ¬P)

Let $H$ and $K$ be two ideals of Lie algebra $L$ such that $H^n \not  \subseteq K $

Now, suppose that $x \in H^n - K$ for some $n \in N$

$\implies$ $x \in H^n \subseteq H  $ and $ x \not \in K$ for any $n \in N$.

$\implies$ $x \in H-K \subseteq H-\sqrt{K} $

$\implies$ $H \not \subseteq \sqrt{K}$

Therefore $H \subseteq \sqrt{K}  \implies H^n \subseteq K \textit{ for some } n \in N $

Comment: How this  is true ?! $$x \in H-K \subseteq H-\sqrt{K} $$

Comment: why this is not true ?!